# How do you cast a dictionary<int, child> to dictionary<int, parent>?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have:

```
public class Animal
{
    virtual public void Attack() {};
}
public class Lion : Animal
{
    public override void Attack() { base.Attack(); }
}
public class Boar : Animal
{
    public override void Attack() { base.Attack(); }
}
```

And containers of these two types of animals:

```
Dictionary<int, Lion> lions;
Dictionary<int, Boar> boars;
```

Is there a way to cast 'lions' and 'boars' so that I can pass them into a function like this?

```
void IterateTable(Dictionary<int, Animal> dictionary)
{
    foreach(var entry in dictionary)
        entry.Value.Attack();
}
```

Comment: Yeah recreating the tables is probably not acceptable as I'm going to have a lot of them.  I may just have to rework this if casting is not possible.  Thanks!

Comment: Define "A lot." Unless you're talking about thousands, you'll likely not see a significant performance hit.

Comment: Or just make the function itself generic so it accepts any of those dictionaries: `void IterateTable<T>(Dictionary<int, T> dictionary) where T : Animal`

Comment: Not sure why you don't just use `Dictionary<int,Animal>` for everything to start with and skip the conversion silliness. Polymorphism / virtual dispatch takes care of making sure the right `.Attack()` is called. For that matter, why not just use a `List<Animal>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
void IterateTable<T>(Dictionary<int, T> dictionary)
    where T : Animal
{
    foreach(var entry in dictionary)
        entry.Value.Attack();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code works as written. When the Animal in the dictionary's value has its Attack() method called, it invokes the appropriate, animal-specific method. This is called [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance?redirectedfrom=MSDN). You can provide a more specific type to the dictionary than required by its signature.

You can modify your code as follows to see:

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<int, Animal> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Animal>()
    {
        [1] = new Lion(),
        [2] = new Boar()
    };

    IterateTable(dictionary);
}

public class Animal
{
    virtual public void Attack() { Console.WriteLine("Default animal attack"); }
}
public class Lion : Animal
{
    public override void Attack() { Console.WriteLine("Lion attack"); }
}
public class Boar : Animal
{
    public override void Attack() { Console.WriteLine("Boar attack"); }
}

void IterateTable(Dictionary<int, Animal> dictionary)
{
    foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        entry.Value.Attack();
}
```

Output:

> Lion attack
>
> Boar attack

Comment: You can't assign a `Dictionary<int, Lion>` to a `Dictionary<int, Animal>`, however, because the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` generic type is invariant.

Comment: This is really the best answer, from an OOP perspective. The only "improvement" I'd make would be to implement the solution with a generic interface, but that's probably overcomplicating things.

Comment: @JonathonChase: True, though in the general case you can declare a type parameter (of a class/method you control) to be covariant `out T` or contravariant `in T`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you pass in a dictionary, there is nothing preventing `IterateTable` from adding an element to it. That is a problem. Since `IterateTable` thinks it's a `Dictionary<Animal>`, it could add either a Boar or Lion, or both. This would obviously not work.

```
void IterateTable(Dictionary<int,Animal> dictionary)
{
    dictionary.Add(1, new Boar()); //This would fail if you'd passed in a dictionary of Lions
    dictionary.Add(2, new Lion()); //This would fail if you'd passed in a dictionary of Boars
}
```

Since `IterateTable` doesn't actually have to add any elements to the dictionary, you can change its signature so that it accepts a read-only object such as `IEnumerable<T>`. Because that interface disallows adding anything, it's legal, and the compilation error goes away.

```
void IterateTable(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
{
    foreach (var entry in animals)
        entry.Attack();
}
```

Now you can write this, and it'll compile fine:

```
var lions = new Dictionary<int, Lion>();
var boars = new Dictionary<int, Boar>();
IterateTable(lions.Values);
IterateTable(boars.Values);
```

By the way, this concept is called [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) and is a really really important part of understanding generics.

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` is an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`.

So, the easy way is to use `ToDictionary(), just upcast the value in your value selector:

```
Dictionary<string,Lion> dict  = new Dictionary<string,Lion>( GetMeSomeLions() );

Dictionary<string,Animal> dictAnimals = dict.ToDictionary(
  kvp =>          kvp.Key,          // Key selector
  kvp => (Animal) kvp.Value // Value selector
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If changing the container from:

```
Dictionary<int, Lion> lions;
```

to

```
Dictionary<int, Animal> lions;
```

is a non-starter, then I would just make my call as follows:

```
IterateTable(lions.ToDictionary(
                k => k.Key,
                v => (Animal)v.Value)
            ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to "restrict" the kind of animal that needs to attack.

```
    void IterateTable<T>(Dictionary<int, Animal> animals) where T : Animal
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Animal> entry in animals)
        {
            if (entry.Value is T)
            {
                entry.Value.Attack();
            }
        }
    }

    void IterateTable(Dictionary<int, Animal> animals)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Animal> entry in animals)
        {
            entry.Value.Attack();
        }
    }
```

And you would call them as follows

```
        IterateTable<Boar>(animals);
        IterateTable(animals);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cast<>`

```
IterateTable(
    lions.Cast<KeyValuePair<int, Animal>>()
         .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));
```